# Entgelt, unentgeltlich – Geld, geldlich

Tags: etymology, spelling

Warum schreibt man *Entgelt* und *unentgeltlich* (wie auch *gelten, entgelten, vergelten, Vergeltung* usw.) mit t, aber *Geld* (*Bargeld, Bußgeld, Falschgeld, Kindergeld* usw.) und *geldlich* mit d? Haben alle diese Wörter nicht einen gemeinsamen Ursprung?

Comment: Doch haben sie. Warum sie allerdings unterschiedlich geschrieben werden... keine Ahnung. Ich finde besonders "Entgelt" überraschend

Comment: Zu *Geld* gibt es eine Reihe von Wortstämmen: [Etymologie von Geld](http://www.heinrich-tischner.de/22-sp/2wo/wort/idg/deutsch/g/geld.htm). Auffällig dabei ist, dass der Ablaut -t eine Besonderheit des Althochdeutschen zu sein scheint - vermutlich rühren daher auch die abweichenden Schreibweisen. Bin aber auch kein Experte.

Comment: Jiddisch: "Gelt"

Answer (score 2):

Die in der Frage genannten Wörter mit einem T sind allesamt Ableitungen bzw. Variationen von

### gelten

Das Mittelhochdeutsche Wort ist genau gleich: »gelten«. Es bedeutete:

> zurückzahlen, zurückerstatten, entschädigen, für etwas büßen, Einkünfte erbringen, bezahlen, Wert sein.

Althochdeutsch haben wir:

> geltan

das zusätzlich zu den meisten genannten Bedeutungen auch noch die Bedeutung »opfern« hatte, was auch die Hauptbedeutung der Protogermanischen Wurzel

> *geldaną

ist, die wiederum aus dem Protoindogermanischen Wort

> *gʰeldʰ-

hervorgegangen ist, dessen Hauptbedeutung übrigens »bezahlen« war.

Der Schlusskonsonant war also ursprünglich ein aspiriertes weiches D, dann ein (normales) weiches D, aus dem schließlich ein hartes T wurde.

### Geld

Man wird es bereits erraten haben: Auch dieses Wort sitzt am Ende eines Astes in einem Baum, der aus der protoindogermanischen Wurzel »*gʰeldʰ-« herauswächst. Allerdings gibt es in diesem Baum eine Gabelung, wo sich der »gelten«-Ast und der »Geld«-Ast auseinander entwickelt haben.

Insbesondere ist »gelten« ein Verb und »Geld« ein Substantiv, und daher bedeuten die beiden Wörter schon mal was anderes (wenn auch in engem Zusammenhang)

Das Geld war Mittelhochdeutsch noch

> das gelt

und korrespondierte also damals noch im End-Konsonant mit dem T von »gel**t**en«. Die Bedeutung war:

> Bezahlung, Ersatz, Vergütung, Einkommen, Wert, Preis, Zahlungsmittel, ...

also im Wesentlichen bereits gleich wie heute.

Das althochdeutsche Wort »gelt« bedeutete:

> Zahlung, Lohn, Vergeltung, Opfer

Daneben gab es das altsächsische »geld« (Opfer, Vergeltung, Zahlung), das altenglische »gield« (Opfer, Kult, Zahlung, Tribut), aus dem sich das heutige Wort »guilty« (schuldig) entwickelt hat, und das gotische »gild« (Steuer, Zins)

Noch ältere Variationen leben allesamt in dem Bedeutungsraum

> Schuld, Opfer, für etwas büßen, für etwas bezahlen, ...

Die Bedeutung

> gelt/Geld = geprägtes oder gedrucktes Zahlungsmittel

ist erst seit dem 14. Jahrhundert belegt, wurde damals aber noch selten verwendet. Erst im 16. Jahrhundert nahm das Wort auch im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch diese Bedeutung an.

Was nun den Wechsel von T nach D betrifft, so sieht man bereits am Beispiel »gelten«, aber auch an vielen anderen deutschen Wörtern, dass hier im Lauf der Zeit immer wieder ein Wechsel zwischen den beiden Konsonanten stattgefunden hat, und zwar in beide Richtungen.

Als die Bedeutung von »Geld« weit genug von »gelten« abgekoppelt war, war der Weg frei für eine getrennte Entwicklung des Konsonanten.

---

Zur Ergänzung:

Die **Gilde** (eine Vereinigung zum gegenseitigen rechtlichen Schutz) geht ebenfalls auf die oben besprochene gemeinsame Wurzel zurück, nicht aber das Wort **Gold**.

»Gold« (gemeinsam mit »Glas«, »gelb«, »glotzen«, »glühen«, »Glatze« und »Galle«) geht auf das proto-germanische »*gelwaz« zurück, was »glänzen, glitzern« bedeutet.

Answer (score 1):

*Entgelt*/*unentgeltlich* kommt von *gelten*, ähnlich wie *abgegolten*, ursprünglich von ahd. "geltan" => "(zurück)zahlen, entschädigen, opfern, wert sein"

*Geld* hingegen kommt vom ahd. "gelt" => "Bezahlung".

Siehe: http://dwds.de/?view=1&qu=geld und http://dwds.de/?qu=entgelt

Zitat von dort:

> Neben der Schreibung mit -d im Nhd. (aus flektierten Formen des Mhd.) hält sich auslautendes -t bis ins 17. Jh., in Entgelt (s. gelten) bis heute.

Comment: Der Vollständigkeit halber solltest Du aber auch erwähnen, dass das Substantiv auf das Verb zurückzuführen ist.

Comment: Wo steht's denn?

Comment: In dem von Dir Zitierten: „Geld [...] ist ein Verbalsubstantiv zu dem unter gelten (s. d.) behandelten Verb.“

Answer (score -3):

Obwohl alle den gleiche Ursprung haben, sind sie doch alle sehr unterschiedlich alt.

z.B. `Kindergeld` wurde erst im 20. Jhd eingeführt, `vergelten` hingegen sehr viel früher. In dieser Zeit haben sich die Schreibweisen auseinander entwickelt.

Ein anderes Beispiel sind die Wörter `Zelle` und `Keller`.

Sie stammen beide vom gleichen lateinischen Wort `cella` ab, das zwei mal eingedeutscht (?) wurden. Zuerst sprach man es (im lateinischen) noch *zella* aus, später dann *kella*.

Comment: Nun gut, Kindergeld ist recht jung und enstand als Kombination aus "Kind" + "Geld". Aber deine Antwort beantwortet nicht im Geringsten die Frage, warum es "Geld" heißt und nicht "Gelt". So war es nämlich im Althochdeutschen.

Answer (score -3):

Ins Blaue gesprochen:

Geld kommt von "guilty", 'schuldig' und ist verwandt mit 'gültig'.
Aus der gleichen Familie kommt 'Gilde'.

Die behauptete Nähe zu 'Gold' ist eher Koketterie
und gibt einen ironischen Querverweis auf den religiösen Charakter 
des sonnenfarbenen 'goldenen Kalbs'.

Comment: Inwiefern soll das eine Antwort auf die gestellte Frage sein? Gefragt wurde nach den harten T am Ende von Entgelt.

Comment: Weil 'guilty' mit 't' geschrieben wird.
Der weltanschauliche Streit liegt m.E. in der Frage, ob es von 'Gold' oder von 'gelten' kommt.

Das Verständnis des Begriffs 'Schuld' ist sehr weit umgreifend.
'Schuld' gibt es in der Juristerei, Mathematik, Ökonomie und Psychologie gleichermassen.